# MatLab equivalent of charAt() in java

Tags: java, matlab

I'm a beginner in MatLab, but I have had a lot of experience in java. I'm in the middle of looping through a string, but I need to be able to do a simple method like `charAt()` from java. I have looked on stack overflow and tried to google any equivalent methods but I've been left without a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: The given answers are correct, but: You should consider not looping through the string. In Matlab in many cases operations can be done faster and more elegantly by vectorizing. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Answer (score 3):

Strings are just arrays in Matlab. So you can easily create your own simple `charAt` function:

```
str = 'somestring';
charAt = @(str,idx)str(idx);
```

Then `charAt(str,5)` will return `s` (this simple function does not input validation). However, it's usually just be easier to directly index into the string: `str(5)`.

Note that Java's `charAt` uses zero-based indexing while Matlab is one-based for everything. You can compensate by using `idx+1` to emulate the Java version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looping through an existing string it would be something like this:

```
mystring = 'example'; % The string
for ind = 1:length(mystring) % For loop from beginning to end of string
    current_char = mystring(ind); % Character at the current index of the string
    fprintf(current_char); % Prints the character to screen
end
```

The final printed output after completion of the `for` loop would read `example` in this case.

In Matlab a string vector is treated just like any other vector, and you can access elements of a vector `v` using `v(ind)` where `ind` is the index of the element you want to access. This is what is going on in the line `current_char = mystring(ind)`. Read this for further info: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Warning: string is obsolete and will be discontinued. Use char instead.`

Comment: Sorry, initially had a mistake in my code (had "string" instead of "mystring"). I corrected it in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charAt` from java in matlab if you want:

```
str = 'somestring';
strJava = java.lang.String(str); % convert to java string
strJava.charAt(5) 
ans =

t
```

Comment: Thanks but it explicitly has to be Matlab